# Preventing button image highlight when selected swift 4

Tags: swift, xcode10, ios12

I do my swift project using code only no storyboards, so no storyboard solutions please I have an agree to terms button and when selected the checkmark is covered in the tint color I am trying to prevent the tint color highlighting the image when selected I am not sure why this is happening here is the button code

```
let agreeToTermsAndConditions : UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.tintColor = .gray
    button.backgroundColor = .white
    button.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = false  
    button.setImage(UIImage(named:"unchecked" )!, for: .normal)
    button.setImage(UIImage(named:"agreechecked" )!, for: .selected)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(userAgreedToTerms), for: .touchUpInside)
    
    return button
}()
```

[image]

The code is running on xcode 10.2.1 using swift 4 and iOS 12 deployment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
UIButton(type: .system)
```

to

```
UIButton(type: .custom)
```

Now you have *complete* control over the look and behavior of the button.

Comment: This has unintended side effects though for me. It makes the button different when highlighted.

Comment: @Eric Yes, that's the intention. If you have a question because of that, ask it as a _question_.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific. It changes the "highlighting" effect which is intended. However, it also changes the actual image itself to the "selected" or "unselected" image, even though the button isn't technically selected or unselected yet (since it's only highlighted). I can post a question about it if this is unclear.

Comment: You should post a question about it whether it's clear or not. I'm not going to respond in the _comments_ to a question that is satisfactorily answered. If you have a question for something you want help with, ask it as a _question_.